# What does Obj::* mean?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

What does Obj::* mean? 
What is it called?

```cpp
template<typename Return, typename Obj, typename... Args>
void
addRouteSyncReturn(
                   Return (Obj::* pmf) (Args...),
)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Your question is "what does `Obj::*` mean." That question is "why does C++ have this pointer to a non-static data member of a class." What is the difference? ;-)

Comment: and *"member"* can be a *method*(function), as in your case, so "pointer on method" or "pointer on member function".